# Save my red currant bush from weeds?

Tags: weed-control, weeds

My "raised" beds are infested with weeds and way too high maintenance, so I am planning on completely obliterating the garden, putting down weed block fabric, topping it with sand and rocks and pavers, and then getting some aluminum feed containers with fresh soil to plant in.

However, there is a large currant bush I don't want to leave behind. I could try digging it up and replanting it in one of the containers, but worried I will kill it and maybe even take the weeds with it's soil.

Or maybe there's a way to block the weed around it? Maybe tape up the stems and seal the ground with weed block fabric and rocks? Anything like that exist? I tried a rubber tree ring, but the weeds climb up through the gaps anyways. Mostly the vine weeds (morning glory?).

Any good ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planning to move it you should prune all the branches back so they are only a few inches from the main trunck. Then dig it up and remove all the soil from the roots. Trim the roots so they are only about 8 inches long. Soak the roots for about one hour in clean water. Then plant it in its new location.

Alternatively, if you don't want to do this and don't mind a multi year process, ribes are perfect candidates for layering. Get a few heavy rocks, and select some branches to become new plants. Lay the branch down on the ground and lay the rock on top of it. Next fall (2016) there should be enough root mass to snip the branch away and plant the clones some place else.

Comment: Couple follow up questions: 1. Can I do this in the spring, say April? 2. Does this also apply to blueberry bushes? Thanks

Comment: It's best to do it in the fall, winter is second best and spring is 3rd best. But rule of thumb (in the northern hemisphere is you can do this with any month with a R in it. IOW, September through April. Still fall is better than spring pretty much no matter what.

Comment: great, thanks. i'm near seattle WA. what about blueberries?

Comment: Ask that in another question. :-)

Comment: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/save-my-blueberry-bush-from-weeds

Answer (score 3):

IMPE red currants transplant pretty well, without any enthusiastic pruning back being done. So you could dig them up, wash them off, plant them, and get new weeds from seed anyway; or you could just spend the time, effort and money on dealing with your weed problem more directly. Up to you.